# Como fazer a minha publicação virar wiki?

Tags: debate, wiki-comunitário

Como colocar minha publicação como wiki?

Comment: Que tipo de publicação? Foi usada na pergunta original a tag "wiki-de-tag" que não tem relação com perguntas e respostas, troquei por "wiki-comunitário". Verifique se é isso mesmo.

Comment: Eu acho que é isso ai mesmo, é que nas minhas conquistas recentes eu fui notificado que ganhei o privilégio "Criar publicações wiki", fiquei com dúvida como implementar essa funcionalidade.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Só moderadores podem fazer isto (pelo menos para pergunta) porque frequentemente é abusado por usuários. Quase nunca devemos tornar uma postagem wiki e se tiver que fazer isto em geral deve-se discutir com a comunidade o motivo para fazê-lo.

Para resposta no momento de editar tem como marcar como Wiki de Comunidade. Mas não faça isso a não ser que tenha um motivo forte. Em geral isso faz mais sentido aqui no meta. Teve momento que fazíamos isso pra organizar melhor (por exemplo responder algo que não era sua resposta mas tinha a resposta no comentário e ninguém respondia, mas hoje ninguém liga pra isso mais, tem tanto problema maior no site).